# MethodAccessException when signing hash in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception, rsa

I'm getting MethodAccessException when executing this line of code:

```
byte[] signedData = rsaProvider.SignData(DataToSign, "SHA1");
```

rsaProvider is instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider which is part of System.Security.Cryptography. Any idea what's going on there and/or how to solve the issue?

Comment: Any details in the` MethodAccessException` that could aid in people helping you out?

Comment: Exception message is "Attempt to access the method failed: System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider..ctor()" and Inner exception is "Could not evaluate expression". What else could be helpful?

Comment: My mistake. I accidentally mixed SignData and SignHash functions. Should be ok now.